# PERC 5 no option to change learn cycle to Auto

Tags: dell-perc

To avoid WUG alerts I am changing all PERC battery learn cycles to warn. I am not able to figure out how to change the learn cycle from auto to learn on any of my PERC 5. The PERC 6, H700 & H800 show Learn Mode in Server Administrator, but it is not listed on the PERC 5. 
Per Dell, I should be able to alter the learn mode on a PERC 5.

I am using the command changing the controller/battery number as needed: 
omconfig storage globalinfo action=service_changelearnmode controller=0 battery=0 learnmode=warn

I received the following message on PERC 5: 
Change Learn Mode is not applicable or cannot be set for this controller.

Is there any way around this or any other way to stop the battery from automatically charging?

Answer (score 0):

What firmware is running on your PERC 5? My first guess would be that the option was added to later firmware versions for the PERC 5. If it's heavily out of date; This would likely be the reason.

I believe the option may not have even existed until mid-late Perc 6 days or even around the time the H700/800 started coming out. DELL was just kind enough to apply the addition retroactively to previous versions in new firmware updates.